Make .NET Core project target specific .NET Windows Desktop Application
I am trying to build a .NET core project that uses this target framework:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>

However, how can I specify that the project uses a specific version, in this case, version 8.0.2?
Thank you in advance

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection

Set the roll-forward to Disable or LatestPatch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#control-roll-forward-behavior

Thank you Rajesh and Thank you Charlie,
The desired solution for me is a combination of both your answers, by adding this to my .csproj file:
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>8.0.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
<RollForward>Disable</RollForward>


Have you tried by added runtimeframewrok version
<TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeFrameworkVersion>8.0.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>


Thank you for answering, I added it now, rebuild and cleared the nuget cache. Still seems to use the latest installed version.

In you solution try to update global.json and specify the sdk it need to pick. "sdk": {
"version": "8.0.2"
}
